# Applying for a UK tourist visa

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am self employed, sole proprietor, meaning am not necessarily required to be on a monthly payroll, because there is no such evidence in my personal account. I do have a separate business account set up. 
For the purposes of my trip, I received payment for some goods I sold and deposited into my personal account to cover my trip. This money I received as payment typically forms part of my personal investment done a few months back into Afro products( non taxable) which is what I mainly trade in. I have receipts and declared the total Amount received in my VAT exempt section

Do I need extra explanations, I intend to submit both business and personal account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit documents to prove your declared income eg tax return, certified trading accounts. Also make sure you’ve considered the points mentioned in this excellent answer [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)